# Does Entity framework accept/add data of an int PK that is not auto-incremented?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table that has an int PK and I did not implement auto-incrementation for it. I wanted to add the data from my client application. If I try to add without auto-incremented int PK I get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The property 'id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Inner exception:

> The property 'id' is part of the object's key information and cannot
>   be modified.

Well, I'm not modifying anything. I'm just trying to add a line. What's going on?

**EDIT**

As per request here's my code

```
var size = new IMF_Size();
            foreach (var item in sizeFromConsolidator)
            {
                if (anthill.IMF_Size.Where(w => w.Brand == item.Brand && w.Category == item.Category && w.SizeCode == item.SizeCode).Count() == 0)
                {
                    size.id = item.id;
                    size.SizeCode = item.SizeCode;
                    size.Name = item.Name;
                    size.Brand = item.Brand;
                    size.Category = item.Category;

                    anthill.IMF_Size.Add(size);
                    anthill.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: "Well, I'm not modifying anything." -- Then you wouldn't be getting this exception. The exception stack trace should show you exactly where your key's property setter is getting called, and for which entity.

Comment: What does the generated class look like?

Comment: @Kamo sure thing. I will edit.

Comment: @hvd Exactly. But really I'm just adding data.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi id is the primary key but I don't want it automatically incrementing numbers on its own. I want to handle the data from my client application.

Comment: Try this.

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID {get;set;}

or try with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Assign

Comment: is this code first or db first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your construction of `size` is outside of the loop.

The first time you get to the `size.id = item.id;` line, your `size` is a new entity. You set its properties, you add it to `anthill`, and you save the changes.

Then you go through the loop again. You get to the `size.id = item.id;` line again. But you haven't constructed a new `size`. You really are modifying an existing entity at that point.

That's exactly what the exception is telling you, too. Move the construction of `size` to within the loop.

Answer (score -1):

> Put this over the propierty of the class to DB like says **Prasad Kanaparthi**

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```